# Terminology on pullbacks

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, terminology, relations

I'm quite confused with the use of pullbacks, and in particular I wonder which terminology I shall use in the following examples. Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets.

1. Suppose that $f,g:X\to Y$ and I know that there exists $h:X\to X$ such that $f = g\circ h$.
   Shall I say that $h$ is a pullback (of $f$? $g$?), or how shall I call $h$?
2. Suppose that $R$ is a relation on $Y$ and $f:X\to  Y$ is some map. I define $S$ on $X$ by
   $$
     xSx'\quad \iff \quad f(x)Rf(x').
   $$
   Shall I say that $S$ is a pullback of $R$ along $f$, or how shall I call $S$?

Comment: You could call $h$ a morphisms $f\to g$ in $(\mathbf{Set}\downarrow Y)$.

Comment: In the first case $h$ isn't necessarily a pullback. If $X=\{1,2\}$, $Y=\{1,2\}$, $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=2$ then the pullback of $f$ and $g$ should be the emptyset with the unique function from the emptyset to $X$ being the two projections. The function $h(1)=2,h(2)=1$ has the property that $f=g\circ h$ but this is not the pullback of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: You can maybe say that $f$ factors through $g$ via $h$. I think most people would understand that terminology.

Comment: @DanielRust: thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just don't call it a pullback.
2. Yes this is ok.

Comment: Thank, would you say there is no special term in the first case?

Comment: As suggested by Stefan Hamcke, you may call $h$ a morphism from $f$ to $g$. Or a morphism *over $Y$*. Or a factorization of $f$ through $g$.

Comment: factorization sounds good, say $f$ factors as $g\circ h$, thanks